# Can I mine diamonds with TNT

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been playing mcpe on the raygun seed. I marked my spawn and I have a truck load of TNT and one flint and steel. While I was mining after a really long time I noticed I had no pick! I was already next to the diamonds and no I am wondering. Can I get diamonds usingTNT?

Comment: If you do decide to try this, use only one TNT block, or else the additional blocks will destroy any dropped diamonds.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the same laws of TNT in the PC/Mac game apply to the Pocket edition, then yes, you can!

**However**, there are two things to keep in mind:

1. 75% of the diamonds will be instantly "vaporized" in the explosion instead of dropped as items
2. You cannot use a [*Fortune* enchantment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments) when using TNT

Using those numbers, while using a *Fortune III* pickaxe to mine diamonds will net you an average of 2.5 diamonds per ore block, using TNT to mine will net you 0.25 diamonds per ore block.

So, although you **can** mine any ore with TNT, it's definitely not efficient (but could theoretically help out in a pinch).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the same laws of TNT in the PC/Mac game apply to the Pocket edition, then no, you cannot. By placing TNT, you will end up destroying the resources, so don't risk it.

> However, since it will wind up destroying most dropped items, it is of no use in breaking blocks to collect their resources.

This is off the Minecraft Wiki under the TNT page: https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT

I suggest trying to find some iron and then mining it otherwise you will lose those precious diamonds. Do not try using TNT. If you have already, unlucky :(

Comment: This is *wrong*. See IQAndreas' answer for the correct answer.

Comment: @Arperum Technically, the answer isn't wrong, it's just [_something something_](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/143023/5438).

Comment: @IQAndreas 25% off is quite a way off in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

With the TNT update, yes. Tnt will now drop every material it blows up.
However, two things to think about:
One: TNT will blow up any item on the ground. So your first tnt will drop everything. And if the diamonds are not picked up before the second TNT explodes, they will disappear.
Two: You can use a Machine Bore to mine diamonds very efficiently with TNT: I suggest searching Ilmango tunnel bore machine on youtube for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Java Redstone != Bedrock Redstone, that machines for java

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot, you will just blow up your items.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the one already provided?